# URL regex suggestion

Tags: regex

I have multiple landing pages that I need to use Google's A/B testing tools on but the naming of the URL's means I need to use regex.

I need a rule that will only match the following URL:

```
domain.com/advertorial
```

But not match:

```
domain.com/advertorial/version1 (could be version5 10 100 etc)
```

We are testing the index file within the advertorial directory against the versioned directories.

The issue is that different suppliers add parameteres to the URL and may include a / at the end.

I've saved a Regex Test: https://regex101.com/r/Ra318C/2

We need a way to say does the URL only contain:

- advertorial
- advertorial/
- advertorial?param=etc
- advertorial/?param=etc

But also not to match if the url has an extra directory e.g.

```
domain.com/advertorials/version1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want [`advertorials$`](https://regex101.com/r/Ra318C/3)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegEx [`domain\.com\/advertorial(?:\/(?:\?[^\/]*)?$)?[^\/]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/IDMkzM/3)

- `domain\.com\/advertorial` matches `domain.com/advertorial` litterally
- `(?:\/(?:\?[^\/]*)?$)?` includes the case where your url ends with `advertorial/`
- `[^\/]*` matches anything but a `/` 0 or more times
- `$` makes sure you're at the end of the String

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/IDMkzM/3)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't overthink things!**

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^domain\.com\/advertorial\/?(\?.*)?$
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://regexr.com/3s7nk)

---

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Beginning of the string
- `domain\.com\/advertorial`: Target the main URL (domain.com/advertorial)
- `\/?`: Optional backslash
- `(\?.*)?`: Optional query string
- `$`: End of the string

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

`/domain\.com\/advertorial[\/]?(?:$|\?.*$)/`

for your test strings:

```
domain.com/advertorial/version1?test=true
domain.com/advertorial/version1
domain.com/advertorial
domain.com/advertorial?test=true
domain.com/advertorial/
domain.com/advertorial/?test=true
```

(Only last 4 will match)

See [regex online test](https://regex101.com/r/SDMZHq/2/)

**Some explanations if needed**

I used *non-capturing group* with *OR* (`|` symbol) conditional:

`(?:$|\?.*$)`

to match what will be after desired URL:
- whether it will be end of the URL (`$` symbol)
- or URL parameters starting with `?` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[a-z\-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,}\/[a-z0-9\-]+\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\=]*)*$
```

Check the test case here https://regex101.com/r/o1hQT4/2

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

`domain\.com\/advertorial\/?(?:\?[^\/]+)?$`

**Explanation**

- `domain\.com\/advertorial` match domain.com/advertorial
- `\/?` Match an optional forward slash
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\?` Match an optional questionmark
  - `[^\/]+` Match not a forward slash one or more times
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert the end of the line

  [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dWHbU2/1)